# LG TV not playing video/playing wrong video with ConnectSDK

Tags: ios, video, television, lg, live-connect-sdk

I am trying to play a MP4 video on a LG TV using the Connect SDK 1.4.1. We have a working implementation with Chromecast and Apple TV.

When first starting our app, we are able to successfully connect to the LG TV. When trying to play one of our own videos the first time, we receive no response from the Connect SDK, nor do we see the video play on the TV. In the console output, it appears that the TV disconnects from the app. The console output can be seen in the Console Output below.

However, we are able to successfully play the [Sintel](http://ec2-54-201-108-205.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/samples/media/video.mp4) video provided in your demo. After playing that video, any future attempt to play a video from my app results in the Sintel video being played instead.

I used [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to redirect the path to the Sintel video, to a video used in my app, and found that the video played fine. This appears to be a communication issue between the App and the TV causing this unintended behavior.

Am I doing something wrong that is specific to the LG platform? Is there any additional information I can provide to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Specs:
ConnectSDK 1.4.1 (installed using Cocoa Pods)
Platform: iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)
LG TV Model #: 47LA6200 (January 2014)
Stream Format: MP4; H.264@1280x720; AAC 44100 Hz Stereo

Console Output.

```
[DEBUG] Did open connection on socket 27
[DEBUG] Did connect
[DEBUG] Did start background task
[DEBUG] Did open connection on socket 29
[DEBUG] Connection received 909 bytes on socket 29
[DEBUG] Connection received 350 bytes on socket 27
[DEBUG] Connection on socket 29 preflighting request "NOTIFY /RenderingControl/45d7f4f5-ebfc-4d0b-f5bd-79e51d2b2006/event.xml" with 909 bytes body
[DEBUG] Connection on socket 29 processing request "NOTIFY /RenderingControl/45d7f4f5-ebfc-4d0b-f5bd-79e51d2b2006/event.xml" with 909 bytes body
[DEBUG] Connection received 2379 bytes on socket 27
[DEBUG] Connection on socket 27 preflighting request "NOTIFY /ConnectionManager/45d7f4f5-ebfc-4d0b-f5bd-79e51d2b2006/event.xml" with 2729 bytes body
[DEBUG] Connection on socket 27 processing request "NOTIFY /ConnectionManager/45d7f4f5-ebfc-4d0b-f5bd-79e51d2b2006/event.xml" with 2729 bytes body
[DEBUG] Did open connection on socket 32
[DEBUG] Connection sent 122 bytes on socket 29
[DEBUG] Did close connection on socket 29
[VERBOSE] [192.168.1.121:49291] 192.168.1.144:38356 200 "NOTIFY /RenderingControl/45d7f4f5-ebfc-4d0b-f5bd-79e51d2b2006/event.xml" (909 | 122)
[DEBUG] Connection received 1724 bytes on socket 32
[DEBUG] Connection on socket 32 preflighting request "NOTIFY /AVTransport/45d7f4f5-ebfc-4d0b-f5bd-79e51d2b2006/event.xml" with 1724 bytes body
[DEBUG] Connection on socket 32 processing request "NOTIFY /AVTransport/45d7f4f5-ebfc-4d0b-f5bd-79e51d2b2006/event.xml" with 1724 bytes body
[DEBUG] Connection sent 122 bytes on socket 27
[DEBUG] Did close connection on socket 27
[VERBOSE] [192.168.1.121:49291] 192.168.1.144:38355 200 "NOTIFY /ConnectionManager/45d7f4f5-ebfc-4d0b-f5bd-79e51d2b2006/event.xml" (2729 | 122)
[DEBUG] Connection sent 122 bytes on socket 32
[DEBUG] Did close connection on socket 32
[VERBOSE] [192.168.1.121:49291] 192.168.1.144:38357 200 "NOTIFY /AVTransport/45d7f4f5-ebfc-4d0b-f5bd-79e51d2b2006/event.xml" (1724 | 122)
2015-01-13 16:47:32.843 Connect-Demo[1853:1424495] TeamStreamConnectVideo downloaded manifest...
[DEBUG] Did disconnect
[DEBUG] Did end background task
```

Comment: @Steg123, could you post a link to the video you're trying to play, so we can try it on our TVs?

> After playing that video, any future attempt to play a video from my app results in the Sintel video being played instead.
Can you please describe the steps more clearly?

Thanks.